# Error in React Native after installing document picker

Tags: react-native, expo

I've been receiving the below error in my React Native project when i installed 'react-native-document-picker' :

[image]

This has started happening after including *import DocumentPicker from 'react-native-document-picker'* in my project (I installed the package using *npm i react-native-document-picker*).

```
import React, { useCallback, useState } from 'react';
import { Button, SafeAreaView, Text } from 'react-native';
import DocumentPicker from 'react-native-document-picker';

export default function File({ onChange, placeholder }) {
    const [fileResponse, setFileResponse] = useState([]);

    const handleDocumentSelection = useCallback(async () => {
        try {
            const response = await DocumentPicker.pick({
                presentationStyle: 'fullScreen',
                type: [DocumentPicker.types.allFiles],

            });
            setFileResponse(response);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }, []);
    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
            <Text>{placeholder}:</Text>
            {fileResponse.map((file, index) => (
                <Text
                    key={index.toString()}
                    style={styles.uri}
                    numberOfLines={1}
                    ellipsizeMode={'middle'}>
                    {file?.uri}
                </Text>
            ))}
            <Button title="Select " onPress={handleDocumentSelection} />
        </SafeAreaView>

    )
}
```

I've included my package.json content below:

```
{
  "name": "tesarsela",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.7.15",
    "@apollo/react-hooks": "^4.0.0",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.0",
    "@graphql-tools/schema": "^10.0.2",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^3.3.4",
    "@ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider": "^2.2.2",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^7.6.2",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.12",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.9",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.17",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.1.0",
    "apollo-boost": "^0.4.9",
    "apollo-cache-inmemory": "^1.6.6",
    "apollo-client": "^2.6.10",
    "apollo-link-ws": "^1.0.20",
    "expo": "~50.0.7",
    "expo-blur": "~12.9.2",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "^12.7.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.11.1",
    "graphql": "^15.8.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.50.1",
    "react-native": "^0.73.4",
    "react-native-country-picker-modal": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-deck-swiper": "^2.0.16",
    "react-native-document-picker": "^9.1.1",
    "react-native-dropdown-select-list": "^2.0.5",
    "react-native-image-slider-box": "^2.0.7",
    "react-native-maps": "^1.10.0",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^9.0.1",
    "react-native-radio-buttons-group": "^3.0.8",
    "react-native-signature-canvas": "^4.7.2",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.6.0",
    "react-redux": "^9.1.0",
    "rn-country-picker": "^1.0.1",
    "yup": "^1.3.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```